# 500 Internal Server Error - python cgi

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, cgi

im new with Python CGI Programming and i start with getting errors :(

so i start a simple 'hello world' script but i got 500 Internal Server Error

**the index.py file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/Python27/python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

print "hello world"
```

**.htaccess file:**

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Add ExecCGI
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py .cgi
DirectoryIndex index.py
```

i tried with chmod but same problem :( help me please

Comment: You should look in the apache error logs.

Comment: did you do `sudo chmod 755 index.py`?

Comment: @bigOTHER i did in the htaccess file before ' chmod  -x '

Comment: @pvg im using windows (localhost)

Comment: @script0r shouldnt it be `chmod +x` for index.py?

Comment: Apache logs in windows as well.

Comment: @bigOTHER yeah thats is i mean that :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` would override `Options ExecCGI`. To resolve this use `Options +ExecCGI` and also add `SetHandler cgi-script`